# Trying to set a UIImageView as background - where is the Layout Menu item

Tags: objective-c, ios, layout, uiimageview, interface-builder

I want to set an image as a setting's page's/view's background image.  I have already created my Settings page and I have the image. I apply a UIImage View but I can't seem to set it as the background image in Interface builder.

Forum posts like this one:

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=715391

seem to imply there is a 'Layout' menu item that I can pick in IB and from there select 'Send to back'. But I can't find this anywhere in Interface Builder. Am I going nuts or has this been removed from the latest version of Xcode.

If it has, is there anyway within interafce builder to send my .png image as a background image for the page.

Thanks

...Dale

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am hoping that you are using a `UIImageView` as background image and inserting it into your view hierarchy. There are 2 ways you could do this -

**1.From IB** - Forget about 'Send to back', a simpler way to set your view hierarchy is -

[image]

here in the view hierarchy, `mapView` is topmost and the `UIImageView` is at the bottom most. IF you want to change this hierarchy all you need to do is drag the view and move them up or down. hope this is clear.

**2.From Code** - You can either insert it any where in your view hierarchy and push it all the way to the back with `sendSubviewToBack:` or you can make the UIImageView the parent view.

Comment: Srikar!!!! You are a life saver!!!! Man! I tried using this hierarchy by dragging all the other buttons/lables etcl ONTO the UIIMageView (hoping they would end generating a sub-folder. That didn't work. But what you suggested works PERFECTLY  DAH!!!!! I didn't even think to try that. THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Ah! I didn't know there was a way to 'accept' an answer. I'm new here. did clicking on the green check mark do the trick? If not, please let me know how to accept an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Another way you can use an image as a background, although it requires code, is to set the view's background colour to an image.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]
  self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:backgroundImage];
}
```

I wish there was a way to do this in Interface Builder.

Comment: Wow, that's an interesting, albiet, round about way of doing things! :) Thanks.